# Why the last background job hangs in bash?

Tags: bash

Here is a script written for bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 &
sleep 2 &
sleep 3 &
for t in {10..0}
do
#   jobs
    echo "Waiting("$t")..."
    JCNT=`jobs | wc -l`
    echo "JCNT="$JCNT
    if [ $JCNT -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
exit 0
```

It works for 10 seconds, but not for 3 seconds as expected. But if to uncomment the "jobs" command then it works fine. I don't have any idea why. Can you help me?

The script output with "jobs" commented:

```
Waiting(10)...
JCNT=3
Waiting(9)...
JCNT=2
Waiting(8)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(7)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(6)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(5)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(4)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(3)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(2)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(1)...
JCNT=1
Waiting(0)...
JCNT=1
```

And with uncommented "jobs" command:

```
[1]   Running                 sleep 1 &
[2]-  Running                 sleep 2 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 3 &
Waiting(10)...
JCNT=3
[1]   Done                    sleep 1
[2]-  Running                 sleep 2 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 3 &
Waiting(9)...
JCNT=2
[2]-  Done                    sleep 2
[3]+  Running                 sleep 3 &
Waiting(8)...
JCNT=1
[3]+  Done                    sleep 3
Waiting(7)...
JCNT=0
```

**ADDED**

I modified the script this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1 &
sleep 2 &
sleep 3 &
for t in {10..0}
do
    KKK=`jobs`
    echo $KKK
    echo "Waiting("$t")..."
    JCNT=`jobs | wc -l`
    echo "JCNT="$JCNT
    if [ $JCNT -eq 0 ]; then
        break
    fi
    sleep 1
done
exit 0
```

...and found that there is info about the last job which is done:

```
[3] Done sleep 3
```

Calling "jobs" simply purges the list of done jobs. Doing "jobs|wc -l" is the wrong way to count active jobs. The right way is "jobs -r|wc -l".

Answer (score 0):

It doen't answer your question, just as hint:

when you execute job seperatly in the loop. It works / count as expected.

But don' have a glue why, for now.